# Java TimerTask using Timer#schedule never runs

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I'm trying to get a Java (1.7) repeating `TimerTask` to work e.g.

```
TokenJanitor janitor = new TokenJanitor( TokenManager.getInstance() );
try {
    new Timer().schedule(janitor, System.currentTimeMillis()+15000, 15000);
    LOG.info("TokenJanitor is running...");
    ...
```

And then the `TokenJanitor` is a `TimerTask` e.g.

```
public class TokenJanitor extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LOG.info("Running TokenJanitor cleanup now...");
        System.out.println("Hello..."); // just for good measure
```

It doesn't even run once. I see the log message after the `schedule` function is called, but I can't see any log messages or print output from the `TimerTask`. I'm using log4j but I'm using it exactly as I do in every other class and it works fine. For what it's worth, I'm using Jetty to run a web server, so the `schedule` function above is called in the main method of a class that launches the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the method [Timer#schedule(TimerTask task,long delay,long period)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) that you have used of  `Timer` class.

```
task - task to be scheduled.
delay - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.
period - time in milliseconds between successive task executions.
```

you have specified `System.currentTimeMillis()+15000` as delay that is very long time to run the task.

Comment: You're right, of course. Silly mistake on my part. I was specifying the actual time in milliseconds as the delay i.e. the millisecond value that the task should first begin. Thanks for the help.